# Does non-clustered index contain any data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So every resource online seems to just copy-paste same phrase that "non-clustered index does not conataint data instead it contains pointers to the actual data"

But in this case - how does rdbms know how to sort it? Does not make sense to my smooth brain.
Let's say I have employees table with `ID` and `LastName`. Isn't it so that if I create NCI on `LastName` leaf page will contain that name value and pointer to the row in the table?
What does it mysterious index page actually contain?

```
employee
ID, LastName
1, CrookedTeeth
2, Bob

Index
Bob, pointer ->2
CrookedTeeth, pointer -> 1
```

Comment: "every" "resource" "online". I'd need to see a link to a single source that makes such a claim...

Comment: This one for example: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9133/sql-server-non-clustered-indexes/

Comment: I'd recommend using a [primary source instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver16): "The pointer from an index row in a nonclustered index to a data row is called a row locator. The structure of the row locator depends on whether the data pages are stored in a heap or a clustered table. For a heap, a row locator is a pointer to the row. For a clustered table, the row locator is the clustered index key"

Comment: Of course a non-clustered index contains data, what good would it be otherwise - it contains data from the columns it was defined on and any included columns

Comment: "data" in a non-clustered index includes the index key columns, clustered index key columns, and included columns. Queries that need only those columns do not need to access data rows (covering index).

Comment: And the statement "the leaf pages of the index do not contain any actual data, but instead contain pointers to the actual data" is flat out wrong. Leaf pages can contain key column data, and can certainly contain `INCLUDE` columns also. It will always contain the row locator also. You might want to find better online resources to read, such as https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/10/how-to-think-like-the-sql-server-engine-adding-a-nonclustered-index/

Answer (score 0):

Lot of comments on this one but the summary is:

- Nonclustered indexes do contain data
- The data contained in a nonclustered index are the columns that index is defined on (covers)
- Also any columns defined as `INCLUDES`, the data is persisted to the index
- And finally the row locator is also contained in the nonclustered index
- The row locator will be the clustered index key when the table has a clustered index (and therefore stored in a B-Tree data structure)

  - The larger the clustered index key, the larger the nonclustered index will be
- Otherwise the row locator will be the `RID` (Row ID) when there is no clustered index on the table, meaning the table is stored in a [Heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) data structure